# pip install don't work in PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I installed "PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3" and python 3.10.5 and connected between the two.
now I want to install some packages, but when i use the command "pip install sockets" for example I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" install sockets': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

someone know how can I fix it?

Comment: It's python 3.8 or 3.10?

Comment: in the settings of the project the interpreter is python 3.10